# Is it possible to recolor iPhone SDK's UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I would like to change the blue color of the UISwitch in iPhone SDK to another color but there is not a tintColor property for this control. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using the built-in `UISwitch`; you'll have to roll your own `UIControl` subclass. If you're developing for 3.2 or later, `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` are probably your friends; with earlier SDKs, you're gonna be doing a lot of manual touch handling.